# Emacs MELPA auto-complete not working with ESS (R) 15.03

Tags: r, emacs, autocomplete, ess, melpa

### Context

I have installed 'auto-complete-20150408.1132' using the MELPA repository from within Emacs-24.3.1 (`M-x package-install`); the OS is RedHat. Auto-completion with popup is working perfectly for C/C++ files etc.  However, I cannot get it to work with ESS[R] 15.03-1.

### ~/.emacs:

```
;; general

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20150609.2145")

(require 'popup)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132")

(require 'auto-complete)

(require 'auto-complete-config)

(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20150408.1132/dict")

(ac-config-default)

;; ESS R specific

(add-to-list 'load-path "/opt/R/ess-15.03-1/lisp/")

(load "ess-site")

(setq ess-use-auto-complete t)
```

### Behavior

I start up emacs, then M-x R session within emacs and perform a few calcs and all is fine but no auto-complete.  Then `C-x C-f` a blank file 'test.R' and type a couple of commands but there is absolutely no hint of any auto-complete.

I have searched and tried many combinations (also Marmalade repository) but simply cannot get it working and would really appreciate some insights as to what I have missed.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi LegalizeIt; I tried exactly your approach. So to be clear if I type library() and then 'Ctrl-Enter' it in test.R it evaluates and prints out the packages in the R window.  Auto-complete then works on the 'library()' function but on nothing else.  If i do the same with 'seq()' then auto-complete also works on seq().It is as if auto-complete only works after you have typed at least once.  It is as if the auto-complete is missing some sort of dictionary of the available function names...!

Comment: emacs tells me the following:ac-source-R is a variable defined in `ess-r-completion.el'.
Its value is ((prefix . ess-ac-start)
 (candidates . ess-ac-candidates)
 (document . ess-ac-help)),  so it can see it under ~/.emacs.d/elpa/lisp/   The thing is when I look under ./auto-complete-20150408.1132/dict/ I see all these *-mode files with the many keywords there.  Should ess-R not have something very similar to this, i.e. a file in a 'dict' directory.  So long story short it is still not working I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm seeing this in the *ESS* buffer "(inferior-ess: waiting for process to start (before hook)" I hadn't realised before but I don't R is fully loading properly even though I can evaluate functions in the 'R' buffer.  Perhaps this latest version has a bug ... any ideas how I can dig into exactly what and where something is failing?

Comment: Thank you for your help; I think you are right and the real problem is tangential to what I thought it was! I'll raise a new question.

Comment: Solved it: Turned out I had modified the R prompt to an illegal character and the load up was failing silently.  I renamed my .Rprofile to 'bak' and loaded M-x R and all worked fine. Slowly, line at a time, I narrowed it down to the prompt changing line.  Many thanks for your help!